# Unable to open module file mainform.vb

Tags: vb.net

This error happened and I don't know what caused it:

[image: Error description screenshot]

What is that `00 00 00 00 00`?

I was working on the project and writing code in `mainform.vb`, and turned off my PC. When I opened again it gave that error AND when I tried to open my project it gave this error:

> Error 3   Unable to open module file
>   'G:\Rienst\Rienst\Rienst\MainForm.vb': System Error
>   &H80041feb&   G:\Rienst\Rienst\Rienst\MainForm.vb 1   1   Rienst

Comment: Those zeros are Hex code. Perhaps the file is corrupted... Have you tried opening it with Notepad?

Comment: I'v tried but it gives 'nul'. and file isn't corrupted because i've opened it yesterday and was working fine.

Comment: If Notepad gives you 'nul' and Visual Basic will only read it as hex code then it's definitely corrupted. Try right-clicking the file and press `Properties`. Then go to the `Previous Versions` tab, select the version from yesterday and press `Restore...`.

Comment: I don't see Previous Versions can you give more information in an answer.

Comment: Oh wait, you have got Windows 8 right? I will have to look up Previous Versions for W8 instead of W7.

Comment: I have got windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: Okay this explains it pretty well: http://winhowto.blogspot.se/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-recover-previous.html | **Short version:** 1) Open a random folder and type `\\localhost\C$` in the address bar. 2) Navigate to the folder where your file is located (Usually ...\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\<project>\<project>\). 3) Right-click the file, click `Properties`, go to the `Previous Versions` tab, select the file from yesterday and press `Restore...`.

Comment: mm in pervious versions tab i don't found anything `'There are no pervious versions avaible'`

Comment: @AhmedAlaa Do you have File History enabled in Windows 8?

Comment: @VisualVincent That'll only work if the OP backed up their system regularly.

Comment: Previous versions is only shown if the feature is enabled. by default, it is NOT. The problem here is that the file is corrupted. Nothing can be done unless you have a backup or used something like TFS to then redownload the file (but from a previous version). I highly suggest to TFS your projects - its free for up to 5 users using Visual Studio online.

Comment: That means no solution. Anyway I started to write the codes again. But please tell me how to activate this OP backed up , so if i lose anything i can retrieve it back.

Comment: It's described in the same link as I gave above on how you activate the backup thing. http://winhowto.blogspot.se/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-recover-previous.html

Comment: Also refer to this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/how-use-file-history

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I know, but my system seems to backup pretty often then, because it has a backup almost every day. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply the answer is using Previous versions. For more information I refered to http://winhowto.blogspot.se/2012/09/… .